# jQuery Carousel Flex 3D Carousel

Tags: jquery, gallery, slideshow, carousel

I've implemented this carousel which works fine, but when I click through all the images taking me back to the start of the carousel, the carousel spins back through all the images to the first image. I've got a jsfiddle set up here to show the problem —

http://jsfiddle.net/s0h28mop/6/

```
rotate_int
```

Is where I think the problem might lie. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the following line to find the position of the clicked image:

```
new_int = -1 * $(this).index();
```

So if your current image has the index `5` and you click the one to the right of it which has the index `0` (because it is the first of the 6 images), the clicked image will always have the smaller index, and thus the rotations moves backwards. You can solve this if you add the number of current rotations to the clicked index like this:

```
var rotations = Math.floor(rotate_int / size);
new_int = -1 * $(this).index() + (rotations * size);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xr4m7he5/1/